# R: positioning of the legend and length of the lines in the legend

Tags: r, graphics, legend, legend-properties

I can't set the location of the legend properly, I have tried to play around with `xjust` and `ncol` but it still appears in the middle of the graphic.

Can you help it align it to the border (left or right I do not care)?

Moreover is it possible to draw shorter lines in the legend? These appear too long.

```
 par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
 plot(1:109,rnorm(109), type="l",col="blue", lwd=2, 
      main="Compare signal and std deviation MC3 ch44",
      ylab="signal", xlab="locations")
 par(new=TRUE)
 plot(1:109, rnorm(109), ylab="",xlab="", type="l", 
      col="red",xaxt="n",yaxt="n", lwd=2)
 axis(4)
 mtext("std. deviation",side=4,line=3)
 legend("topright",col=c("blue", "red"), lwd=2,
        legend=c("signal","std dev"), cex=0.85, bty="n", xjust=1)
```

Comment: It appears in the upper right corner when I run your code. Perhaps start a clean R session and try again.

Comment: Zooming in R-Studio shows it a lot more centered than after the exporting in .pdf, probably due to the scaling factor of the plot (?) But is it possible to plot a shorter line in the legend? Can't find the option anywhere..

Comment: Try the `seg.len` argument in `legend`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments restarting an R session and using

```
legend("topright",col=c("blue", "red"), lwd=2,
 legend=c("signal","std dev"), cex=0.85, bty="n", xjust=1, seg.len=0.5)
```

solved my problems.

Comment: It is often true that legends and text will show up in the "wrong" place if you change the plot window size after plotting.  Best to set the window size first if you want a specific aspect ratio.  E.g. `dev.new(width=3,height=9)`